# How to make GridBagLayout specific size?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

At the moment I've got a 9x9 grid of text fields using a `GridBayLayout`. Because the grid makes each text field slighter longer than it is tall (even when I set a specific height for the text field), the grid is a rectangle, rather than a square.

How can I either make the entire grid a specific size, or each text field inside the grid a specific size?

EDIT: I need the 9 x 9 grid of text fields to be square, rather than rectangular.

[image]

Comment: Do you expect a full tutorial here? Please show what you've tried so far following the rules here: [MCVE]

Comment: @STaefi I was more curious if there's some kind of constraint I could use

Comment: Strange influx of 9x9 text field GUI related questions recently, seems like homework is due.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with sizing hints, methods `[get/set][Minimum/Maximum/Preferred]Size` are telling the layout manager what size the component wants to be and layout managers sometimes ignore that and sometimes they don't. `GridBagLayout` respects that and your `JTextFields` are tellimg him that they want to be rectangular. How `JTextFields` figure out what size they want to be is all kinds of difficult so let's leave that out.

If you want to make sure that all your `JTextFields` are of the same size, you should override these methods. Subclass `JTextField` and make something like this:

```
final class SquareJTextField extends JTextField {
    private static Dimension maxDimension = new Dimension(0, 0);

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
        // take the larger value
        int max = d.width > d.height ? d.width : d.height;
        // compare it against our static dimension
        // height je rovnaky ako width
        if (max > maxDimension.width)
            maxDimension = new Dimension(max, max);
        // return copy so no one can change the private one
        return new Dimension(maxDimension);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
        int max = d.width > d.height ? d.width : d.height;
        if (max > maxDimension.width)
            maxDimension = new Dimension(max, max);
        return new Dimension(maxDimension);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
        int max = d.width > d.height ? d.width : d.height;
        if (max > maxDimension.width)
            maxDimension = new Dimension(max, max);
        return new Dimension(maxDimension);
    }
}
```

All objects of this class should be the same dimension and should be square.

Replace `JtextFields` in your grid with `SquareJTextField`

Comment: If GridBagLayout sespects sizing hints, wouldn't it be easier to set it instead of subclass ? Just wondering...

Comment: I think in this case the JTextFields are telling the Layout what size they are, which means while the GridBag could presume a certain size, the JTextFields will still remain the size they want to be, and may end up overlapping or going off the end or something.

Comment: @Betlista It is generally a bad idea to set the sizing hints with the setters. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) is the reason why I am avoiding it.